# Yocto is giving root a password

Tags: linux, ssh, yocto

I am using Yocto to create a linux image for an iMX6. I am using Yet Another Terminal (YAT) and Command Line to interface with the device image. I added

```
inherit extrausers
ROOTPASSWORD = "root"
ROOTUSERNAME = "root"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P ${ROOTPASSWORD} ${ROOTUSERNAME};"
```

To `core-image-full-cmdline.bb`

Using YAT this password takes hold. However using the terminal I can not SSH into my device. Using

```
ssh root@192.168.1.7
```

This should log in automatically as Yocto does not set a default password. When I enter root as the password I am not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

By default Yocto configures SSH servers to prevent root logins. I'll skip the reasons why that's a good idea, but you have a few options.

1. Create a non-root user, SSH with that then `su` using your root password.

```
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " \
    useradd -P ssh_password ssh_user; \
    usermod -P root_password root; \
"
```

2. Configure your SSH server to allow root logins.

   - Dropbear: add a bbappend to modify `dropbear.default` removing `-w` from the args
   - OpenSSH: add a bbappend to modify `sshd_config` adding `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` to allow certificate logins or `PermitRootLogin yes` to allow password logins.